# GoDaddy Managed WordPress loading 2 different stylesheets with different time stamps

Tags: css, wordpress, web, caching, hosting

I am developing a website on a GoDaddy managed wordpress host. After updating the stylesheet, I've been noticing unanticipated results. After looking into it, the website is serving two different versions of the stylesheet. An older one, and a newer one with the recent changes. This ofcourse causes conflicts. There is a button for the GoDaddy managed wordpress to 'Flush Cache.' However, this does not fix the issue. I do not see any way of disabling the caching. Has anyone seen this before? Any recommendations?

The two different stylesheets look like this:

secureserver.net/wp-content/themes/THEME-NAME/style.css?ver=3.4.1&time=1683924350
secureserver.net/wp-content/themes/THEME-NAME/style.css?ver=3.4.1&time=1683058432

I have tried:
-Flushing Cache via GoDaddy 'Flush Cache' button
-Changing Stylesheet version
-Disabling the GoDaddy caching (Could not find a way)

Comment: Welcome to the community @WebDeveloper! As a general practice, try to give your questions subheadings, bold & italic highlights, and other formatting, etc. that makes it better to read.  This makes more people be interested—at a glance—in reading your question, upvoting it, etc. which will help it to reach more people.

Answer (score 0):

As well as **server caching**, there are other types of caching that can cause problems with a website:

You might have **WordPress caching** in your website itself e.g. if you are using any caching plugins, or a plugin that includes it's own caching such as performance optimisers or code minimisers. These are easy to fix (once you identify them all) - you just need to flush the cache in all of them.

Then there is **browser caching** which is more difficult to control because the cache in in your users' browsers. But you can test it on your own by clearing your browser cache and restarting your browser, or better yet try a different browser, because sometimes browsers have very aggressive caching.